# Compiling Haxe without a main entry point

Tags: haxe

I am trying to compile a Haxe class without defining an entry point by using a build `hxml` file.

My folder structure looks like the following:

```
root
|
 ___src
     |___Test.hx
|
 ___build.hxml
```

`Test.hx` has the following contents:

```
package foo;

class BarLib 
{
      public function new()  {}

      public function test() {
            return "Hello from BarLib!";
      }
}
```

`build.hxml` looks like this:

```
-cp src 
--macro "include('foo')"
-js test.js
```

I then run `haxe build.hxml` from the root folder which creates the file `test.js`, but its contents is pretty much empty:

```
// Generated by Haxe 3.3.0
(function () { "use strict";
})();
```

It seems not to be able to locate the package `foo`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should check out this article http://code.haxe.org/category/compilation/compiling-libraries-without-main-class.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declare `Test.hx` to be part of the `foo` package, however, it's placed in a folder named `src`. If you move it to `src/foo`, Haxe produces the following output:

```
// Generated by Haxe 3.3.0
(function () { "use strict";
var foo_BarLib = function() {
};
foo_BarLib.prototype = {
    test: function() {
        return "Hello from BarLib!";
    }
};
})();
```

It's also a bit unusual to have a file named `Test.hx` that doesn't actually define a type named `Test`. `BarLib.hx` might be a better name.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `haxe -cp src foo.Test` to compile a single class (and its references) without an entry point